# latex figure (or table) in a new page

Tags: floats, page-breaking

I'm curious what's the best way to get the table of figure to appear on the *next* page in your document. I've tried the `\newpage` command, which works but is a hassle as I basically need to declare it before each figure and after each figure. I've also tried passing the environment the "`p`" command but then it puts in the end of the chapter, I just want it on the next page. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020) is admittedly rather lengthy, but it might be useful for understanding more about floats in LaTeX.

Comment: `[!p]` should work

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: This only works sometimes. Sometimes I get two figures still on the same page...

Answer (score 1):

`\begin{figure}[p]` should work to force the float to a float page, if you want to allow the float page to have just 1 float even if the float is small, then set `\floatpagefraction` small enough say

```
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{0.1}
```

so that LaTeX does not  need to hold the float back to fit a second float on the page to exceed `\floatpagefraction` (which is 0.5 in the standard classes)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you load the [afterpage](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) package in the preamble and issue the following instructions in the body of the document:

```
\afterpage{%
   \clearpage % flush any accumulated floats
   \begin{figure}[ht!]  % or: \begin{table}[ht!]
   ... % body of figure/table environment
   \end{figure} % or: \end{table}
} % end of scope of \afterpage directive
```

Basically, execution of the instructions in the argument of `\afterpage` is deferred until the start of the next page.